# php code to select sum and count of column

Tags: php, mysql

there are multiple column in my table ..

```
     col1   col2  col3     price
     500    700    100       10
     501    700    100       20
     502    700    100       30
     503    700    100       10
      4                      70
```

I need to get count of col1 and display its sum.

and also display sum of price column...

But the main thing is i need to display this in last row....after all data...how can select this and echo in last row...

plz help me...

**I need to echo exactly as i put the data in above table...**

**I need sql query and also need help to echo only sum of this two column in last row only......**

```
SELECT *,IFNULL(col1,'SUM'), count(*) as count FROM coupon_entry  WHERE Group By col1 WITH ROLLUP


<?php  if (is_array($data)) { foreach($data as $row){ ?>
        <tr>            

            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['col1']); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['col2']); ?></td>          
            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['col3']); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['price']); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to calculate the sum in PHP with variables :

```
<?php  if (is_array($data)) {
$totalCol1 = 0; 
$totalPrice = 0;
foreach($data as $row){ 
$totalCol1 += $row['col1'];
$totalPrice += $row['price'];
?>
        <tr>            

            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['col1']); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['col2']); ?></td>          
            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['col3']); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['price']); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } 
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $totalCol1;?></td>
            <td></td>          
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo $totalPrice;?></td>
        </tr>
}?>
```

Comment: What a waste of time. Just write the query correctly and there is no need to start runnig calculations in PHP.

Comment: I said that's a solution.. There are lots of solutions !

Comment: <?php echo $totalCol1;?>  BUT this display sum Of col1 ..i need to echo count here..how we echo total count....

Comment: FOE Ex- col1 has 4 values like 10,20,30,40 then it display only 4 not sum of all values

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to do 2 separate queries or else you have to do your calculations in PHP - either one is fairly simple although the PHP solution will probably be slightly (negligibly?) faster.

double-query:

```
$r = query('SELECT *
            FROM yada-yada');
while ($row = fetch($r)) {
    echo "<td>$row[col1]</td>\n";
    echo "<td>$row[col2]</td>\n";
    echo "<td>$row[col3]</td>\n";
    echo "<td>$row[price]</td>\n";
}

$r2 = query('SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, sum(col1) as sum_col1, 
               sum(price) as sum_price
            FROM yada-yada...');
if ($row = fetch($r2)) {
    echo "<td>$row['cnt']</td><td>$row['sum_col1']</td>...$row['sum_price']...\n";
}
```

calculate in PHP:

```
$cnt = $sum_col1 = $sum_price = 0;
$r = query('SELECT *
            FROM yada-yada');
while ($row = fetch($r)) {
    echo "<td>$row[col1]</td>\n";
    echo "<td>$row[col2]</td>\n";
    echo "<td>$row[col3]</td>\n";
    echo "<td>$row[price]</td>\n";
    $cnt++;
    $sum_col1 += $row['col1'];
    $sum_price += $row['price'];
}
echo "<td>$cnt</td><td>$sum_col1</td>...$sum_price...\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my sql query to get count and sum of column.

SELECT COUNT(coupon) As Total,SUM(Price) AS TotalPrice FROM coupon_entry

And put this in seprate row below table...

```
<?php   
foreach($tot as $tota) 
?>
        <tr style="background-color:#33CCFF;">
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:right; font-weight:bold;">Total Coupon</td>

            <td><?php echo $tota['Total'];?></td>
            <td style="text-align:right; font-weight:bold;">Total Amount in Rs</td> 
            <td><?php echo $tota['TotalPrice'];?></td>
        </tr>           
            <?php }?>
```